VSCode install error for the hugginface relik library
So I really need to use the python library called relik on VSCode. When I would use pip install relik in the terminal, it would install and everything but when I tested it using this code in a cell
import torch
from relik import Relik

It would give me this error:
{
    "name": "OverflowError",
    "message": "Python int too large to convert to C long",
    "stack": "---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OverflowError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 import torch
----> 2 from relik import Relik
      3 from relik.inference.data.objects import RelikOutput
      5 relik = Relik.from_pretrained(\"sapienzanlp/relik-entity-linking-large\")

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from relik.inference.annotator import Relik
      2 from pathlib import Path
      4 VERSION = {}  # type: ignore

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\inference\\annotator.py:16
     14 from relik.common.upload import get_logged_in_username, upload
     15 from relik.common.utils import CONFIG_NAME, from_cache
---> 16 from relik.inference.data.objects import (
     17     AnnotationType,
     18     Candidates,
     19     RelikOutput,
     20     Span,
     21     TaskType,
     22     Triplets,
     23 )
     24 from relik.inference.data.splitters.base_sentence_splitter import BaseSentenceSplitter
     25 from relik.inference.data.splitters.blank_sentence_splitter import BlankSentenceSplitter

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\inference\\data\\objects.py:8
      5 from typing import Dict, List, NamedTuple, Optional
      7 from relik.reader.pytorch_modules.hf.modeling_relik import RelikReaderSample
----> 8 from relik.retriever.indexers.document import Document
     11 @dataclass
     12 class Word:
     13     \"\"\"
     14     A word representation that includes text, index in the sentence, POS tag, lemma,
     15     dependency relation, and similar information.
   (...)
     35         be attended to, and which should not.
     36     \"\"\"

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\retriever\\__init__.py:1
----> 1 from relik.retriever.pytorch_modules.model import GoldenRetriever

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\retriever\\pytorch_modules\\__init__.py:5
      1 from dataclasses import dataclass
      3 import torch
----> 5 from relik.retriever.indexers.document import Document
      7 PRECISION_MAP = {
      8     None: torch.float32,
      9     32: torch.float32,
   (...)
     23     \"bf16\": torch.bfloat16,
     24 }
     27 @dataclass
     28 class RetrievedSample:

File c:\\Users\\Anjali's Computer\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python312\\Lib\\site-packages\\relik\\retriever\\indexers\\document.py:11
      8 from relik.common.log import get_logger
      9 from relik.common.utils import JsonSerializable
---> 11 csv.field_size_limit(sys.maxsize)
     13 logger = get_logger(__name__)
     16 class Document:

OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long"
}

I think what it is doing is installing relik version 1.6 instead of 1.7. I tried to fix this too by installing the github moduel by just running the command
git clone https://github.com/SapienzaNLP/relik.git
cd relik
pip install -e .[all]

But it would just give me a new error
Obtaining file:///C:/Users/Anjali%27s%20Computer/Desktop/Pipeline/relik
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Checking if build backend supports build_editable ... done
  Getting requirements to build editable ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [26 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "c:\Users\Anjali's Computer\Desktop\Pipeline\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
          main()
        File "c:\Users\Anjali's Computer\Desktop\Pipeline\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
          json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "c:\Users\Anjali's Computer\Desktop\Pipeline\.venv\Lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 132, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return hook(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wsho2hb8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 483, in get_requires_for_build_editable
          return self.get_requires_for_build_wheel(config_settings)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wsho2hb8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 334, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
          return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=[])
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wsho2hb8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 304, in _get_build_requires
          self.run_setup()
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wsho2hb8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 522, in run_setup
          super().run_setup(setup_script=setup_script)
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-wsho2hb8\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 320, in run_setup
          exec(code, locals())
        File "<string>", line 110, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\Anjali's Computer\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
          return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 4687: character maps to <undefined>
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build editable did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.


I tried a few things already like uninstalling all the 1.6 dependency requirement and installing the 1.7 dependency requirements instead then go and run the pip install -e .[all] command but it still doesnt work and results in the same error.

I tried all the possible ways of installing relik listed on it's github. So I tried doing pip install relik[all], pip install relik[train], pip install relik[faiss], pip install relik. None of these works and it all results in the same issue as stated before.

Using relik in google colabs by running !pip install relik[faiss] works perfectly and it properly imports relik 1.7. This is great but I really need it to work in VSCode too.

When i'd run the same command pip install relik[faiss] in VSCode it always imports it in 1.6, even when I would use !pip install relik[faiss] --upgrade.


